# Значение типа "Vector *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "Vector *"

Tags: c++, ооп

Реализую класс вектора в качестве задания по программированию в университете.
Есть класс вектора

```
class Vector
{
private:
    int size;
    float *body;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int size, float val = 0);
    Vector(const Vector &vec);
    float& operator[] (int index);
    Vector& operator= (const Vector vec);
}
```

И класс матрицы, которую я хочу реализовать через динамический список векторов (для удобной работы над строками)

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int size;
    Vector *body;
public:
    Matrix(int n, int m, float val = 0);
    Matrix(const Matrix &vec);
}
```

При реализации конструктора матрицы

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m, float val)
{
    body = new Vector[n];
}
```

возникает ошибка "Значение типа "Vector *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "Vector *""
Какие либо идеи, почему такое происходит, или может быть предложения, как это лучше реализовать? (без использования std::vector))

Comment: `Vector& operator= (const Vector` **&** `vec);` -  попробуйте

Comment: Но ответить никто не сможет, вы не написали пример, чтобы точно произошла эта ошибка. Подозреваю, что у вас циклические `#include`. Покажите все инклуды в `matrix.h` и `vector.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlexGlebe был прав, проблема в циклическом #include, вопрос закрываю